# Realm: Comparing List of primitive types, e.g.: List<String>

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

### What is the intended way to compare Realm's list of strings?

I'm trying to compare 2 lists of strings in Realm, as follows:

```
func testRealmListOfStrings() {

    let strings = ["a", "b", "c"]
    let list1 = List<String>()
    list1.append(objectsIn: strings)

    let list2 = List<String>()
    list2.append(objectsIn: strings)

    // 1. ok
    XCTAssertTrue(list1 !== list2, "instances should not be identical")

    // 2. fails
    XCTAssertTrue(list1 == list2, "instances should be equal by `==` operator")

    // 3. fails
    XCTAssertTrue(list1.isEqual(list2), "instances should be equal by `isEqual` method")

    // 4. ok
    XCTAssertTrue(Array(list1) == Array(list2), "instances converted to Swift.Array should be equal")
}
```

However, this does not work as expected. The test fails on `2.` and `3.`.

According to [how Realm object's Equatable is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877533/1161723) this should work as expected although, the answer does not specify how exactly it's implemented in List.

Comment: I've created an issue on Realm's github: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5665

Comment: Actually, looking into the code base, the hierarchy is `NSObject -> RLMListBase -> List` and the equality is not implemented anywhere, therefore probably the default `NSObject` equality (reference equality) is used. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Or, maybe this is intentional, since `List` is backed by a `RLMArray` which can be loaded dynamically.